# How to display children with in a card widget, and one of the child is fl bar chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, card, fl-chart

This is the error that appeared on my terminal when I run the flutter run command. How can I have two children inside a card without overflowing or extending its size to infinity??

```
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderBarChart#947f3 relayoutBoundary=up24
NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  creator: BarChartLeaf ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ←
    BarChart ← BarChartWidget ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ←
    NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=376.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(376.0, Infinity)
This RenderObject has no descendants.
```

//Code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 20,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: Color(0xff240046),
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            BarChartWidget(),
            Text("Demo"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I also tried SingleChildScrollView too, but not works

Here is the code I used to build the flutter chart.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarChart(BarChartData(
        axisTitleData: FlAxisTitleData(
          show: true,
          leftTitle: AxisTitle(
            titleText: "Interest Rate",
            showTitle: true,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          bottomTitle: AxisTitle(
            titleText: "Banks",
            showTitle: true,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          bottomTitles: BarTitles.getBottomTitles(),
          leftTitles: BarTitles.getLeftTitles(),
        ),
        gridData: FlGridData(checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return value % BarData.interval == 0;
        }, getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: Colors.white,
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
          );
        }),
        minY: 0,
        maxY: 10,
        groupsSpace: 5,
        barGroups: BarData.barData.map((data) {
          return BarChartGroupData(x: data.id, barRods: [
            BarChartRodData(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
              ),
              y: data.y,
              width: 20,
              colors: [data.color],
            ),
          ]);
        }).toList()));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been better to see you `BarChartWidget()` class.

Why not Wrap with an `Expanded()` widget and see.

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column( 
        children: [
          BarChartWidget(),
          Text("Demo"),
       ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

**OR**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: 
    Expanded(
      child: Column( 
        children: [
          BarChartWidget(),
          Text("Demo"),
       ],
      ),
    ),
),
```

This is the reason you are getting the error:
[‘Vertical viewport was given unbounded height’](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/common-errors)

Comment: I added BarChartWidget code , Can you check that ??

Comment: I see your BarChartWidget is not specifying a width or height. Please wrap your `BarChart` widget with an `Expanded` Widget or a Container and provide a `height` value

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. So check.